# Django NoReverseMatch error with valid url config and views

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error in my template rendering.

Here's the relevant template:

```
<ul id='comments'>
{% for comment in comments %}
<li class='comment'>
    <img class='gravatar' src='{{ comment.User|gravatar:50}}' alt='{{ comment.User.get_full_name }}' \>
    <a href='{% url 'dashboard.views.users.profile' comment.User.id %}' class='user'>
        {{comment.User.get_full_name}}
    </a>

    <p class='comment-timestamp'>{{comment.created}}</p>
    <p class='comment-content'>{{comment.comment|striptags}}<br>
    {% if user == comment.user or user = report.user %}
    <a href="{% url 'mokr.delete_comment' comment.id %}">Delete</a></p>
    {% endif %}
</li>

{% endfor %}
```

The error is given on the url 'mokr.delete_comment' line

Here's the view:

```
def delete_comment(request, comment_id):

    comment = get_object_or_404(ReportComment, id = comment_id)
    report = comment.MgmtReport
    comment.delete()

    project = report.project

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show_post', args=(project.url_path, report.id)))
```

and the section of urls.py

```
(r'^mokr/comment/(\d+)/delete/$', mokr.delete_comment),
url(r'^mokr/show/([^\.]*)/(\d+)/$', mokr.show, name='show_post'),
```

Comment: You never named your url, you need `name='delete-comment'` in your url pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your urls.py to add a `name` argument to your delete comment url.

```
(r'^mokr/comment/(\d+)/delete/$', mokr.delete_comment, name="delete_comment"),
```

Then try using this in your template;

```
{% url 'delete_comment' comment.id %}
```

See [naming URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) and [reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing two arguments to the template in your call to reverse in the delete_comment view; `args=(project.url_path, report.id)` but your urls.py lists;

```
(r'^mokr/comment/(\d+)/delete/$', mokr.delete_comment),
```

Which can only accept one parameter.

Comment: At that point, I'm calling reverse on another function, The 'show report' function. I will edit to add this section of urls.py. 
Unless I'm not understanding how the reverse method works properly?

Comment: @user2562438 Sorry! Is mokr a namespace? Perhaps try `{% url 'mokr:delete_comment' comment.id %}`?

Comment: the intent is that i have a report, which has a comment on it. If the delete comment button is hit, the comment is deleted, then a reverse is run on the show method, returning the user to the post's page

Comment: Try `{% url 'mokr:delete_comment' comment.id %}` instead of `{% url 'mokr.delete_comment' comment.id %}`. Note the colon. I'm wondering if this is your [application namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls). Failing that what happens if you just do `{% url 'delete_comment' comment.id %}` ?

Comment: hmm that didn't work. just delete_comment returned the same error

Comment: See my alternate answer.